# rqt ImportError: No module named my_module (different from previous post)

Tags: python, plugin, ros-indigo, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
In my attempt to create an rqt gui in ROS indigo, following the tutorials http://wiki.ros.org/rqt/Tutorials/Create%20your%20new%20rqt%20plugin and http://wiki.ros.org/rqt/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20Python%20Plugin, with the use of a .ui file, I began with just a simple version (two QPushButtons and a QLabel), just to check if it works. Unfortunately, it doesn't, while it gives me this error:

```
RosPluginProvider.load(rqt_mypkg/MyPlugin) exception raised in __builtin__.__import__(rqt_mypkg.my_module, [MyPlugin]):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_gui/ros_plugin_provider.py", line 77, in load
    module = __builtin__.__import__(attributes['module_name'], fromlist=[attributes['class_from_class_type']], level=0)
ImportError: No module named my_module
```

I have checked for other similar questions, like http://answers.ros.org/question/188825/importerror-for-rqt-plugin/ and http://answers.ros.org/question/205408/ros-rqt-plugin-importerror-unrelated-to-previous-post/ (I also had the same mistakes, which I corrected), but still, the same error occurs. I have put my code (and the related files) here:
https://github.com/PanosP/rqt-mypkg-fail .

My environment variables are:

```
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/panosss/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROS_TEST_RESULTS_DIR=/home/panosss/catkin_ws/build/test_results
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=/home/panosss/catkin_ws/devel/share/common-lisp
ROS_DISTRO=indigo
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/indigo/etc/ros
PYTHONPATH=/home/panosss/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/home/panosss/naoqi/pynaoqi-python2.7-2.1.3.3-linux64
```

and I work on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS.
Does anybody have any idea what could have gone wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213968/rqt-importerror:-no-module-named-my_module-(different-from-previous-post)/) by [Panos](https://answers.ros.org/users/23226/panos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-07-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[You have `_init_.py`](https://github.com/PanosP/rqt-mypkg-fail/blob/4e94f0fd4f5e445c13c57ed3d114bae56cf2c39e/rqt_mypkg/src/rqt_mypkg/_init_.py). It has to be `__init__.py`, double-underscore, not single. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Panos](https://answers.ros.org/users/23226/panos/) on 2015-07-19**:
Thank you very very much! (It now gives me some other errors but I will fix them and post when it is ready)

**Comment by [Panos](https://answers.ros.org/users/23226/panos/) on 2015-08-13**:
Just to close it, the "other errors" had to do with the loadUi function, but it is irrelevant with this question (I did it without using ui)